# HDIV config to set parameters in hidden fields instead of URL

Tags: spring-security, spring-mvc-test, hdiv

I am using Spring MVC 4.1.7.RELEASE and HDIV 2.1.11. I have set HdivRequestDataValueProcessor to intercept internal redirects in Controller code as below.

```
return "redirect:"+"/user/account"
```

This is resulting in the HDIV state parameter getting set in the URL. In the HdivRequestDataValueProcessor code, I saw that it is using the LinkUrlProcessor to write the HDIV state as a request parameter to the redirected url.

Is there a way to configure HDIV to have this parameter as a hidden field instead of in the url?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that. You can not use a hidden field in a redirect.

Fernando Lozano (HDIV Team)

Comment: Thanks Fernando. I had kind of guessed it from the code of HdivRequestDataValueProcessor. Would you think that it might be of value to have it configured as a hidden field instead of long URL fields may be in future versions of HDIV? Just suggesting.